# C# TextBox.Text = Multiple words

Tags: c#

is it possible to make more words than one, i have created a timer, which checks what is typed in a textbox, and if write password typed changes a picture, so my other if function don't work, how could i make something like this:

The code of statement, i need something like this: `if (metroTextBox1.Text == "byby", "cow", "root")`

```
if (metroTextBox1.Text == "byby")
{
     Image img = Properties.Resources.Good_Pincode_48px; // Right'as
     metroTextBox1.Icon = img;
}
else
{
    // new wrong().Show();
    Image img = Properties.Resources.Wrong_Pincode_48px; // Wrong'as
    metroTextBox1.Icon = img;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-or-operator

Comment: You can use the ```.Contains``` function

Comment: @Arturthetemplar What about `"list of words".Contains("or")`?

Comment: @DavidG You are right, sorry :^)

Comment: I have a textbox, which checks the writed text, can i make that it to check if the word is "cow", "kitchen", "tree" in one if statement?

Comment: The answer should help. Also: Do not use a timer for this when the TextChanged event is made for the job!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(new string[] { "byby", "cow", "root" }.Contains(metroTextBox1.Text))
{
   ...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Like suggested in the comments you can use a `HashSet` instead of an `Array` to store the words you want to compare. The `Contains` method works faster with a `HashSet` since it has a `O(1)` lookup whereas `Arrays` and `Lists` have a `O(n)` lookup.

```
HashSet<string> words = new HashSet<string>(){ "byby", "cow", "root" };
if (words.Contains(metroTextBox1.Text))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Arturthetemplar No it won't. It checks for the entire word

Comment: Also consider moving the array to a field to avoid instantiating it many times. Also consider using a `HashSet`.

Comment: [Here is why it works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5cf1d56(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll add my 2 cents to Slaven Tojić's answer:

.

- You could create a property with collection of words:

  ```
  private HashSet<string> WordsList { get; } = new HashSet<string>(new[]
  {
      "byby",
      "cow",
      "root"
  });
  ```

.

- And add event handler to `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox`:

  ```
  this.textBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1OnTextChanged;
  ```

.

- And in event handler use collection to check if it contains the
  element:

  ```
  private void TextBox1OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (this.WordsList.Contains(textBox1.Text))
      {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

use this with comparater to avoid case problems

```
      if(new string[] { "byby", "cow", "root" }
         .Contains(metroTextBox1.Text,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
           ...
        }
```

Comment: I believe `StringComparison` in your `.Contains` should be `StringComparer`.

Comment: @TimothyG. it's just to ignore the case when comparing, so do  not need to write a comparer